# Generate 100 random samples of size 30 each in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import random

boston = load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
boston_df['MEDV'] = boston.target
```

Use function random.sample to Generate 100 random samples of size 30 each (set random.seed=1)

Comment: Where is the question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) in list comprehension for list of `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = [boston_df.sample(30) for i in range(100)]
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Answer (score 1):

Or use `iloc` with `random.sample` and a list comprehension:

```
import random
lodf = [boston_df.iloc[random.sample(range(len(boston_df)), 30)] for i in range(100)]
```